# Unable to open socket to localhost port 40006

Tags: localhost, port, pentaho

I am working on pentaho data integration.

When the master(localhost) is trying to send transformation data to slave server (remote host ). I get the below error ;

Carte : Unable to open socket to localhost port 40006

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried a different port?

Comment: Pentaho by itself is trying for this port.
On my machine, when i try to check port, i get below output.

MacBook-Pro:~ tcssig$ lsof -i -P | grep :40006
java       806 tcssig  447u  IPv6 0xac48c4734630e62b      0t0  TCP *:40006 (LISTEN)